# Qt App Ui Multi-Language Support:Change Images Accordingly

Tags: qt, user-interface, multilingual

I use UI Designer to set up the form layout. And I want to change the button background image to another one when language setting is changed in the system setting of the phone. How can I do this? I know how to support multi-language of the text , but I dont know how to support mult-language of the image. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When the language is changed, [`QCoreApplication::installTranslator()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#installTranslator) will be called. From the documentation:

> Installing or removing a QTranslator,
>   or changing an installed QTranslator
>   generates a LanguageChange event for
>   the QCoreApplication instance. A
>   QApplication instance will propagate
>   the event to all toplevel windows,
>   where a reimplementation of
>   changeEvent can re-translate the user
>   interface by passing user-visible
>   strings via the tr() function to the
>   respective property setters.
>   User-interface classes generated by Qt
>   Designer provide a retranslateUi()
>   function that can be called.

So you should reimplement [QWidget::changeEvent()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#changeEvent) in your toplevel window and change the image there if the [`type()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qevent.html#type) of the event is [`LanguageChange`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qevent.html#Type-enum).

Comment: All the images are in qrc file. Does qrc file support multi-language? If it does, is there any example?

Comment: @catinred: Well, it doesn't matter where the images come from. Just load the image you want for a particular language from the resource file and use whatever method you use to draw it as the background of a button.

Comment: But I have dozens of them. Is there any convinient way?

Comment: I don't think Qt provides something to make this convenient so you'll have to find something yourself. Maybe you can name the images based on the language code (e.g. `en.jpg`, `fr.jpg`,...) so these names can easily be constructed at runtime.